# TypeScript Interface with returns types of a function

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have 5 currified functions, taking as first an `Api` object used to make the call, and as 2nd (optional) argument an argument to the api call itself.

```
// functions.ts
function f1 (api: Api) {
  return () => { // returns a Promise<string> }
}

// some other functions

function f5 (api: Api) {
  return (id: number) => { // returns a Promise<number> }
}
```

And now I want to create an Object which has exactly this type:

```
{
  f1: () => Promise<string>
  // ...
  f5: (id: number) => Promise<number>
}
```

Here's what I've done:

```
import * as functions from './functions';

const api = new Api(); // Define the Api object here

const withApi = Object.keys(functions).reduce((result, key) => {
  result[key as keyof typeof functions] = functions[key as keyof typeof functions](api)
}, {} as /* What type should i put here??? */);
```

The best I could find for `/* What type should i put here??? */` is `{ [index:string]: Promise<any> }`, which is not satisfactory at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapped type that will contain keys for all keys in the original functions object but they will be of the same type as the return  type of each function (extracted using the conditional type `ReturnType<T>`)

```
type AllReturnTypes<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any) => any>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>
}
const withApi = Object.keys(functions).reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key as keyof typeof functions] = functions[key as keyof typeof functions](api)
    return result;
}, {} as AllReturnTypes<typeof functions>);

withApi.f1();
withApi.f5(10);
```